# passing multiple variables to function in order to add/remove class Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables

I'm trying to first clear the class of all `options` and then add a class to the option with the corresponding letter.
Here's my function:

```
function setAnswer(b, c){
      $('#'+b+' .option').removeClass("answer");
      $('#'+b+' .option'+c).addClass("answer");  
  }
```

and the form

```
 <div id="belh" class="options">
                <label>a.</label><input class="option optiona"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentnode.id, this.classname)" type="radio" class="a" name="answer">&nbsp;
                <label>b.</label><input class="option optionb"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentnode.id, this.classname)" type="radio" class="b" name="answer">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label>c.</label><input class="option optionc"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentnode.id, this.classname)" type="radio" class="c" name="answer">&nbsp;
                <label>d.</label><input class="option optiond"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentnode.id, this.classname)" type="radio" class="d" name="answer">
                </div>
```

the id for the div `belh` changes dynamically so I pass `this.parentnode.id` onto variable `b` in the function so i can do this:

```
 $('#'+b+' .option').removeClass("answer");
```

remove class from all option elements
now i pass `this.classname` to `c` so i can get the letter (a,b,c,d) to use here:

```
$('#'+b+' .option'+c).addClass("answer");
```

so that if the radio box with class `c` is clicked, all fields with class `option` within the div `belh` will lose the class answer, if they have it. then the field with class `optionc` will have class `answer` added to it. (because: `$('#'+b+' .option'+c).addClass("answer");`). For some reason my function isn't working. I think I'm passing the variables in the wrong way.

Comment: I think you're complicating things too much... Why this `$('#'+b')` and not `$('.options')`?

Comment: because the div (parent to the radio button) is duplicated over and over with different ids and same class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should code `this.className` and `this.parentNode.id`, you can also use jQuery `change` event method and `prev` method for selecting previous sibling of the clicked input:

```
$('#belh input[name=answer]').change(function(){
    $('input.option').removeClass('answer');
    $(this).prev().addClass('answer')
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by "code this.classname", is it just the capital N? sorry noob question.

Comment: @theatomicdude Yes, the name of the property is `className` and the other one `parentNode`.

Comment: wow. Unbelievably, that actually worked (the capitalization), i did not know that mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tried toggle the class name? http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: the accepted answer worked for me, but this looks like a great idea as well. Thanks!